# How can I add the following css code to my page header from functions.php?

Tags: css, wordpress, function

Right now, I'm placing the following code in `header.php`.

I think that solution isn't very elegant.

How add this CSS code from `functions.php` to my header (how would that code look like)?

```
    wp_head();
?>
<style>
    .jimgMenu ul li.landscapes a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'intro_image'); ?>) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    .jimgMenu ul li.people a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'slider_image'); ?>) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    .jimgMenu ul li.nature a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/nature.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }
    .jimgMenu ul li.abstract a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/abstract.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    .jimgMenu ul li.urban a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/urban.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;

    }
    .jimgMenu ul li.people2 a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/people.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
        min-width:310px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: To "call" something, it has to be in a function, or in its own file which you can `include()` or `require()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using hooks is the best way - then you only have to modify functions.php and not the template, making it easier to update the template should the author release changes, updates or patches.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function add_styles()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .jimgMenu ul li.landscapes a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'intro_image'); ?>) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    .jimgMenu ul li.people a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'slider_image'); ?>) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    .jimgMenu ul li.nature a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/nature.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }
    .jimgMenu ul li.abstract a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/abstract.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    }

    .jimgMenu ul li.urban a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/urban.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;

    }
    .jimgMenu ul li.people2 a {
        background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/people.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
        min-width:310px;
    }
</style>

    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_styles');
```

assuming your theme is built correctly and had `wp_head();` in the `<head>`, which in your example it does, you won't need to mod any files besides `functions.php`

---

I will add that for site load optimization and performance enhancement because of client side caching of external style sheets you should make a separate style sheet then instead of the function I mentioned above printing out the CSS it would print out the `<link>` to the styles sheet.

While you can accomplish not using `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` and instead use relative urls (ie. ../images/.....) that would still pose a problem with the `get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'intro_image')` so if your style sheet  changes are really this small what I listed above using the hook is an *okay* solution, if the styles you want to inject into the `<head>` are longer/larger than you listed in the question I would suggest using @erenon's suggestion about a dynamic style sheet and a what I just mentioned about modifying my function & hook to include the style sheet instead of printing the styles.

Comment: Thanks I guess a hook was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily wrap the CSS in a function

```
function headerCSS(){
    ?>
      // YOUR CSS
    <?php
}
```

And then call the function

```
<HEAD>
<?php headerCSS(); ?>
//other header stuff here
<?HEAD>
<BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't *call* it, but you can insert it as css:

```
<link href="generate-css.php" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@janoChen: Assuming your directory structure should look like this

```
/wp-content/
  /themes/
    /your_theme/
      /images/
```

put all those styles without `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` in a `styles.css` file within `/wp-content/themes/your_theme/` and then in your `header.php` simply have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/styles.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bad solution. External stylesheets are cached by the server. The method you're using means they must be served up in every page, and are more resource-intensive on the server side.

Look at using the  tag to set the site resource path instead.

> The base tag is very useful for Web
>   designers who build websites in one
>   location but will ultimately be placed
>   in another location.

See: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/how-to-use-html-base-tag.htm